# Get the elements of NumPy array A where the row indices are equal to the rows in array B that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have two 1D NumPy arrays

```
a = array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
b = array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

how can I get the elements of b that have the same row indices where a == 1 is true (i.e. [0, 0, 1, 0] at indices 0, 1, 3 and 7)?

Comment: `idx = np.where(a == 1)[0]` <----------- this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where` to get the index values.

**Try:**

```
idx = np.where(a == 1)[0]
print(b[idx])
```

**Output:**

```
array([0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: That's not what OP asked for

Comment: @MadPhysicist: This is what `b[idx]` for. `how can I get the elements of b that have the same row indices where a == 1 is true.....`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [134]: a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]) 
     ...: b = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

The `True` elements of `a`:

```
In [135]: a==1                                                                                 
Out[135]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False])
```

that boolean array can be used to index `b`:

```
In [136]: b[a==1]                                                                              
Out[136]: array([0, 0, 1, 0])
```

the indices of nonzero values (aka `np.where`):

```
In [137]: np.nonzero(a)                                                                        
Out[137]: (array([0, 1, 3, 7]),)
```

that index tuple can be used to index `b` (no need to use the `[0]` in other answers):

```
In [138]: b[np.nonzero(a)]                                                                     
Out[138]: array([0, 0, 1, 0])
```